# How to expand a nested list inside an inline list with jQuery slideToggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list that is horizontal (display: inline-block) when you toggle the nested list to expand it pulls all the other `<li>` in the list down with it.

Here's my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLv77/42/).

Obviously I know it can work like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLv77/43/) because the main list isn't displaying inline. But i need it to be inline. If anyone has any idea how to get this to work I would appreciate the input. I've tried searching for the answer and playing around with the code but I'm not having any luck.

Thanks in advance.

CSS:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 280px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative; 
}   

#sidebar-left {
  width: 280px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #ff8000;
  border-right: 10px solid #333;
}

#sidebar-left li {
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu-ebene1 {
  background: #ff8000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.last.closed {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.submenu-ebene2 {  
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #222;
  color: #ccc;
}

.submenu-ebene3 {  
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #222;
  color: #ccc;
}

.submenu-ebene3 li {  
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.link, .single-link {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #222;
  padding: 10px;
}

.link.last, .single-link.last {
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.active {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}

.inactive {
  color: #333;
  -o-transition:.2s linear;
  -ms-transition:.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition:.2s linear;
}

.inactive:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}

.submenu-ebene2 {
  display: none;   
}

.submenu-ebene3 {
  display: none;   
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap the submenus inside the `<li>` element of the parent. With that, you have separated submenus and menus. With your actual code, your submenus are side by side with your parent menus.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating what you mean i can't get my head around it? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't much time now but the idea is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tuornm9z/

Comment: When I arrive to house if you don't solve this I can make a more complete example

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index to your nested elements:

```
.submenu-ebene2 {
     display: none;
    position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
}

.submenu-ebene3 {
     display: none; 
    position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Your list expands because they are nested with in the `<li>` elements.

This will work! Good luck http://jsfiddle.net/pLv77/45/

Comment: If i position it absolutely it won't push whats below it down though will it?

Comment: Play with it, you may have to change it to relative but that is the way to do it.. Give it a go and see what happens..

Comment: position: relative brings me right back to the same problem. This was one of the things I have tried. I just tried it to double check and unfortunately thats the case. I'm not certain your solution is what I was looking for but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You didn't even try what I have given you... It is shame that you would ask for an answer and when one is given you don't even try it.. What I have given you will not push your content..

Comment: I have just said that I tried both what you suggested and then like you said i also tried relative, if you put what you suggested into the demo i provided you will see its not working unless I am doing something wrong? I need it to not push the other <li> in the list however i need it to 'expand' and your solution does not expand if it is positioned absolutely as it won't push any other content that might be below the list downwards.

Comment: I added a wrap under your menu in a demo and with my code the menu expands over that div ... it does not push it which tells me you didn't try it, or you didn't do it right..

Comment: I did exactly what you put in your fiddle. The div containing 'New Stuff Added' should move down when the menu expands. I appreciate your help but I don't think you understand what I need to happen. Positioning absolutely corrects the issue yes however it is no longer 'expanding' in the sense that it expands and pushes content below it down with it.